# How to automatically open files downloaded from Safari?

Tags: macos, safari

When I download mp4 files from Safari, I'd like them to open automatically once they have been downloaded. How can this be done?

Safari Preferences->General->Open "safe" files after downloading is checked.

I want to automatically open file that might not be "safe".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php). I tried using it and it worked smoothly. However, Hazel isn't free ($25).

The second solution is to use [Automator](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uP08R5c5b3o) which is part of Mac OS X.

However, using Automator didn't quite work. Some of the mp4 files did open, but for unknown reason some didn't.

Also I'm not sure if Automator has to open the files as soon as they are downloaded, or there is a time frame which it could take to open them. Maybe some one more experiences with Automator could elaborate on this.

Answer (score 15):

You can add a file extension to the list of "safe" extensions. Once that is done, safari will launch whatever application is associated with that file type.

This is done by creating the file `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.DownloadAssessment.plist` containing the file extension you want opened.

Here is an example, which solves the problem for .torrent files:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com-PropertyList-1.0.dtd"> 
<plist version="1.0"> 
<dict> 
 <key>LSRiskCategorySafe</key> 
<dict> 
 <key>LSRiskCategoryExtensions</key> 
<array> 
 <string>torrent</string> 
 </array> 
 </dict> 
 </dict> 
</plist>
```

More [info here](http://www.corewerkz.com/2009/04/12/safari-open-torrent-files-automatically-after-downloading/).

If the file exists already, edit it and add the `<string>torrent</string>` line under the `<array>`tag

Comment: This solution works great in OS X 10.11 El Capitan 

Comment: Doesn't seem to be present anymore?

Comment: Also works great in OS X 12 Monterey. Thanks! @vy32 if the file doesn't exist then you have to create it. Easiest from the command line (e.g. with vim).

Answer (score 1):

This answer will describe how not to get the following message when you open a file downloaded from Safari for the first time.

[image]

Well, I'm not sure why you're seeing this, but if your files are going to the ~/Download folder, you will have to tell the Operating System that you want that folder out of the quarantine.

Open your Terminal.app (Spotlight for Terminal) and type:

```
xattr -d -r com.apple.quarantine ~/Downloads
```

You *might* have to do it as super user (in which case, use this instead of the above), so if the above fails try with *sudo* before the command:

```
sudo xattr -d -r com.apple.quarantine ~/Downloads
```

***note*: You will be asked for your password if you use sudo, this is normal.**

What is *xattr*?

> The xattr command can be used to display, modify or remove the
>   extended
>        attributes of one or more files, including directories and symbolic
>        links.  Extended attributes are arbitrary metadata stored with a file,
>        but separate from the filesystem attributes (such as modification time or
>        file size).

**WARNING**: By doing the above, the OS will stop caring about files put in the Downloads folder. If you want to only do this for certain files, you will have to download your "safe" files elsewhere and execute the above command in that folder.

If you want to *undo* the operation, simply remove the **-d**

```
xattr -r com.apple.quarantine ~/Downloads
```

The **-r** is to make it recursive (so existing files and folders are also modified).

**UPDATE** I've realized that new files will be put in quarantine when you download them, so although the above command will go file by file and remove the *flag*, so you don't have to tell the OS that the file is safe **every time**, in order to completely disable the mechanism, you have to execute an extra command. **please make sure that this is ok with you, since you can't do this for single files, it's an all or nothing**.

**To Disable the warning dialogs completely for any files in the future**, execute this command (Again, I'm not 100% sure if you need sudo, just try without it first.:

```
defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSQuarantine -bool NO
```

And if you ever want to **revert** the change:

```
defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSQuarantine -bool YES
```

I can't recall if you need to logoff/logon again or reboot.

Good luck and be careful with those downloads. :)

*A restart **IS** required after these commands*.

Link attached for further reading on the [Quarantine](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3662).

Comment: I've updated the answer, have you tried the second command?

Comment: Yes, I understand it. The way it works is that safari will open (certain) safe files. But the definition of safe is "is not in quarantine". So until you "manually" try to open it and get the dialog (and accept the file is safe) this flag will prevent the file from opening. I'm surprised tho' because mp4 should open automatically, maybe there's something else going on here. Try with the 2nd command and tell me how it goes. You have to restart after that.

Comment: did you restart after you executed the commands? It's a system wide service so you have to restart.

Comment: And what is *the way I used to* ? how are you downloading files? Do you have a sample that I can try? (shall we go to the chat?) :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7533/discussion-between-martin-marconcini-and-anonymous)

Comment: Martín Marconcini, please delete all the comments added to this answer so people who read your answer will understand it. Also, I'm editing your answer with my comment above.