# Command line 'open' for app not installed from App Store

Tags: command-line

So on MacOS, we can use the command line `open` command, to run an app, e.g.,

```
open JD-GUI.app/
```

However, when the application has just been downloaded from somewhere, then this gives the alert/popup that the app "cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified". I know that I can use the Mac GUI and right-click ctrl-"open" to give me option to open it anyway. However, `man open` does not show any corresponding option to do this from the command line. I tried holding down the "ctrl" key while pressing "Return" on command line, and it didn't work either.

Is it possible to do this from the command line?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82370/how-to-automatically-open-files-downloaded-from-safari/82374#82374

Comment: This looks like an ugly way to achieve such results. There is no simpler way?

Comment: Yes, right-click > Open ;)

Comment: The simple way is to take the command from the linked answer and turn it into a shell script/function which calls both `xattr` and `open` :-)